# Loop wont break

Tags: java

Hey I have a simple tic tac toe game for an eclipse, but the loop won't break. The loop fills up my board with 2s. The loop is at the end method computerInput(). The loop still won't break after setting done = true in the while(!done) scope.I have to go for a little while. Thanks for the help though guys! I'll be back in a few hours.

```
package lab15;

public class WinnerCheck {

    public static int PL_ONE = 1;
    public static int PL_TWO = 2;
    static Console console   = new Console();
    static final int PAUSE   = 500;
    public static int i = 3;
    public static int j = 3;
    public static int[][] b  = { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 } };


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean done = false;

     while (!done) {
    printBoard(b);
    playerOneInput();
    pause(PAUSE);
    computerInput(b);
    detectWinner(b);
    console.clear();
    int result = detectWinner(b);
    if(result > 0) done = true;
}
```

}

```
    public static void pause(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }


    public static boolean placePiece(int[][] b, int r, int c, int player) {
        b[r][c] = player;
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isWinner(int[][] b, int player) {
        // check for a horizontal winner
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
                if (b[i][j] == player
                    || b[j][i] == player ) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count == b[i].length)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static int detectWinner(int[][] b) {
        if (isWinner(b, PL_ONE)) {
            return 1;
        } else if (isWinner(b, PL_TWO)) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static void printBoard(int[][] b) {
        System.out.println("------");
        for (int[] row : b) {
            for (int element : row) {
                System.out.print(element + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("------");
        System.out.println("winner: " + detectWinner(b));
    }


    public static void playerOneInput() {
        switch (console.getKey()) {
        case '1':
            placePiece (b, 0, 0, 1);
            break;
        case '2':
            placePiece (b, 0, 1, 1);
            break;
        case '3':
            placePiece (b, 0, 2, 1);
            break;
        case '4':
            placePiece (b, 1, 0, 1);
            break;
        case '5':
            placePiece (b, 1, 1, 1);
            break;
        case '6':
            placePiece (b, 1, 2, 1);
            break;
        case '7':
            placePiece (b, 2, 0, 1);
            break;
        case '8':
            placePiece (b, 2, 1, 1);
            break;
        case '9':
            placePiece (b, 2, 2, 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    public static void computerInput() {
    boolean placePiece = false;
        for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
                if (b[i][j] == 0) {
                    placePiece(b, i, j, PL_TWO);
                    placePiece = true;
                    if (placePiece == true) {
                        break;
                }
                if (placePiece == true) {
                    break;
                }

                }
                }
            if (placePiece == true) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I guess it isnt that simple

Comment: which loop are you referring to?

Comment: You never set done to true to break your loop? That loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!done) {
    printBoard(b);
    playerOneInput();
    pause(PAUSE);
    computerInput();
    detectWinner(b);
    console.clear();
```

You're not setting `done` to `true`.

Comment: I set done = true; in the while (!done) scope but it crashes the console. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Where in those methods are you setting done to true?

Comment: I put in
int result = detectWinner(b);
if(result > 0) isDone = true;
after the console.clear();

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using return value from detectWinner method

`int result = detectWinner(b);
if(result > 0) isDone = true;`

Comment: I tried putting your code into my while(!done) scope but it's still looping through the entire board. The game ends now when I get a winner, but doesn't solve the looping issue.

Answer (score 0):

for the computerInput loops, you are in a method, you can use return instead of break

Comment: I changed the all the break; to return; but it still loops forever filling the board with 2s.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clear few things? May be I am not getting it right.

```
computerInput(b);
```

`ComputerInput` is a static method which take no argument and you are supplying an int[][] as an argument to it. It should not compile in first place.

```
detectWinner(b);
```

Can show the code of method `detect` which take an int[][] as an argument and return an integer.

```
int result = detectWinner(b);
```